# Page not found after clicking on pagination

Tags: posts, pagination

I'm using this code to display page pagination on my website. But when I click to go to the second page it shows me "Page not found" error.

Does someone know what is wrong with my code that is not displaying the posts on the second page?

```
<?php
$currCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_name = $currCat->name;
$cat_id   = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query- 
>query('showposts=3&post_type=post&paged='.$paged.'&cat='.$cat_id);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>


<div class="module-container">;
<div class="content">;

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); 
?></a>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
global $wp_query;

 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 echo '<div class="paginate-links">';
 echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) 
) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'prev_text' => __('<<'),
'next_text' => __('>>'),
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
echo '</div>';
 ?>
```

Comment: A 404 is determined by the results of the *main query*, not the query you create in the template. Alter the main query with [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) rather than create a new query.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had to change the amount of post per page in my WordPress dashboard > Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most.

Comment: That doesn't really fix the problem, it just hides it. You'll have the same issue again when the number of pages in your custom query exceeds the number of pages in the main query.

Comment: Can you show me how do I add the action in my main query?

Comment: Have you read this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Answer (score -2):

Just set the permalink to numeric ( Under Setting -> Permalinks ). This works for me.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?